# How to securely delete individual files (documents) on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, privacy

My understanding is that when files are deleted on a computer (and here, I am considering the iPhone a "computer"), those files are typically recoverable using forensic tools. I know there are easy ways to delete *everything* securely, however...

How can one delete individual files on the iPhone such that they are unrecoverable, without deleting everything?

Comment: Only thing I know that you can delete on iPhone is contacts, calenders and photos. What files do you want to delete from where exactly? :)

Answer (score 1):

This app in Cydia seems like it would do the trick (provided it works as advertised):

http://cydia.saurik.com/package/iwipe/

The app works by making a very large file that takes up all the free space in the user memory and writes zeros to all the bits. So to securely delete individual files, one would simply (insecurely) delete them (marking them as free space), and then wipe free space with the above app.

Comment: Although, personally I'm a bit wary of using an obscure, closed source tool like this. Hard to know if it is actually working the way it is supposed to. For all I know it could be sending all the data to a server somewhere before it wipes it.

Comment: This approach to overwriting doesn't work reliably on flash storage, because of the allocation tricks the memory controller uses (see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6278/how-to-securely-erase-an-ssd-drive/6287#6287)). Basically, it may overwrite all "free" space, but that turns out not to include all of the formerly-used blocks in the flash memory.